# How can I mirror a project hosted on launchpad on github?

Tags: git, github, bazaar, launchpad

I want to contribute actively to a project that is hosted on Launchpad.
I'm much more comfortable with GitHub, and would like to continue to use it if possible.
Would I be able to mirror the bzr repository on github?

If it's possible, how could I set this up?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could try some kind of git-bzr bridge like this **<del>[git-bzr](http://github.com/pieter/git-bzr)</del> [git-bzr](https://github.com/termie/git-bzr-ng)** script:

> This script allows you to add bazaar repositories as git branches in your git repository.
>   After that, you can fetch the Bazaar repo, make some changes, and push it back into Bazaar.

The reverse is possible, meaning you can clone a bzr repo and push to your GitHub repo with **[bzr-git](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/migration/en/foreign/bzr-on-git-projects.html)**.

Comment: That one worked well.
I ended up using a bash fork of the project, to remove the ruby dependency. Thanks a lot.

Comment: for a more up to date project for git-bzr stuff go https://github.com/termie/git-bzr-ng

Comment: @Globalkeith thank you. I have edited the answer to point to that version.

Answer (score 1):

Beware: trunk bzr-fastimport is **broken** and may corrupt your 'marks' file..

https://code.launchpad.net/~xrg/bzr-fastimport/re-tailor

A detailed implementation here:
http://git.hellug.gr/?p=xrg/openerp-rebzr;a=shortlog;h=refs/heads/fast-only

Answer (score 0):

I have just written [a detailed how-to for mirroring a Launchpad Bazaar repo to Github (note that it focuses on Mac users)](https://medium.com/@GregDubicki/mirroring-bazaar-repository-into-git-on-a-mac-6ff137444fa6).

A minimal version of this how-to:

1. Install bazaar and a plugin to make it work with git

```
brew install bazaar
brew tap gdubicki/tap
brew install gdubicki/tap/bzr-git
```

2. Clone the Bazaar repository

```
# for example:
bzr branch lp:update-motd
```

3. Create the Git repository

You’ll need is the URL to the repo, in my case:

`git+ssh://git@github.com/gdubicki/update-motd-for-non-ubuntu.git`

4. Push the clone to the remote

```
cd update-motd # or whatever is the name of the Bazaar branch
PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages" bzr dpush -v git+ssh://git@github.com/gdubicki/update-motd-for-non-ubuntu.git,branch=master
```