# Cant push changes back to Launchpad using git-bzr

Tags: git, bazaar

I'm unable to push my changes back to a Launchpad repository using git-bzr.

```
$ git init
$ git bzr add upstream ../bzr-branch
$ git bzr fetch upstream
$ git checkout -b local_branch upstream
```

Then I modify a file, README for example.

```
$ git add README
$ git commit
$ git bzr push upstream
```

And I get the following error.

```
/usr/bin/git-bzr: line 219: cd: lp:jakaa: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can depend on the exact flavor of **`git-bzr`** you are using (there are several forks on GitHub):
The <del>[kfish one](http://github.com/kfish/git-bzr)</del> [`git-bzr-ng`](https://github.com/termie/git-bzr-ng) is the most up-to-date, compared to the [pieter one](http://github.com/pieter/git-bzr) I mentioned to you in [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294076/how-can-i-mirror-a-project-hosted-on-launchpad-on-github/3294096#3294096).

[This thread](http://osdir.com/ml/general/2010-04/msg09571.html) mentions:

> > Sadly, git-bzr is sufficiently broken that you will not be able to push your changes with "`git bzr push upstream`", as the docs indicate.
> >     Instead, we have to use "`git format-patch`" and then turn each patch into a Bzr commit  manually, which get pushed with "`bzr push`".
> >     Once pushed, "`git bzr pull upstream`" reflects that new commit back in Git:
>
> Again, it looks like a straightforward enough, programmatic change that `git-bzr` could be fixed to just do it.
>   Kind of a shame about the rebasing requirement, if someone's got local branches; why is it needed? Is this process unable to push content or commit info into bzr in a way that matches the git version?

Comment: Hi.
I didn't expect the same person to answer the question, so thanks.
Yes I'm using the kfish version. I didn't want to have ruby as a dependency.

Thats too bad about the script being broken. I wish someone would fix it. I'd try but my familiarity with bzr/git is abysmal.

Thanks though.

Comment: So I revisited the git repo, and saw the mention of a python rewrite. That one seems to fix all the issues I had. Thanks